# Issues with Binary Search Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, search, binary-search

I have an assignment to write a binary search that returns the first iteration of the value we are looking for.  I've been doing some research online and my search looks a lot like what i'm finding but i'm having an issue. If I pass this code an array that looks like this {10,5,5,3,2} it find the 5 at in the middle(The first thing it checks) and then just returns it. But that is not the first iteration of the 5 it is the second.  What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

The code(I'm using Java):

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int v){
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length-1;
    while(lo <= hi){
        int middle = (lo+hi)/2;
        if(v == arr[middle]){
            return middle;
        }
        else
        {
            if(v < arr[middle]){
                lo = middle+1;
            }  
            else
            {
                hi = middle-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: For binary search to work, your array has to be sorted first. You find `5` at position `2` because it is the middle element in the first iteration and won't work finding other elements. To find the first occurrence is possible and it is called the `lower_bound`

Comment: There are two possible ways to fix it: 1) after a hit, continue the search on the left side to find possible other occurrences. 2) after a hit check the neighboring elements on the left one by one until you reach the first one. Option 2 should only be done if you know that duplicates don't occur often as it may degrade to O(n) effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified algorithm that works.

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int v) {
  int lo = -1;
  int hi = arr.length - 1;

  while (hi - lo > 1 ) {
    int middle = (lo + hi) / 2;
    if (arr[middle] > v) {
      lo = middle;
    } else {
      hi = middle;
    }
  }

  if (v == arr[hi]) {
    return hi;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

The key points are:

- The interval (lo, hi] is exclusive to the left, inclusive to the right.
- At each step we throw away one half of the interval. We stop when we are down to one element. Attempts to terminate early offer only a minimal performance boost, while they often affect code legibility and/or introduce bugs.
- When `arr[middle] = v` we assign `hi = middle`, thus throwing away the right half. This is safe to do because we don't care any occurrences of `v` past `middle`. We do care about `arr[middle]`, which may or may not be the first occurrence, and it is for this reason that we made (lo, hi] inclusive to the right. If there are occurrences of `v` before `middle`, we will find them in subsequent iterations.
- As a side note, the more natural definition `[0, n)` inclusive to the left, exclusive to the right, can be used to find the last occurrence of `v`.

In my experience, this inclusive-exclusive interval definition produces the shortest, clearest and most versatile code. People keep trying to improve on it, but they often get tangled up in corner cases.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but if you are looking for the value stored in index 0 this will not find it correct? Eventually it will check if arr[1] > v that will be false.  Then it will set hi = 1. 1-0 = 1 which is not greater than 1 so it doesn't check the last index because the while loop returns false?


To fix this you would have to change the while loop to be (hi-lo >=1).

Comment: It does work; after checking `arr[1] > v`, it sets `hi = 1` (`lo` is still -1). Then the last iteration sets `middle = (1 + (-1)) / 2 = 0` and subsequently `hi = 0`. At this point `hi - lo = 1` and the function returns `hi`, that is 0.

Comment: Oh when I did my calculations I had lo set to 0 like in my original code. My bad, thanks for the clarification.